# Microsoft word 2003 crashes when pasting info

Tags: microsoft-word, copy-paste, microsoft-office-2003

Often I want to copy info from a web page into a text file for various reasons.

I select the text on the web page, copy and then try to paste it into Word.

I often find that word just hangs and I have to hard close it.

Is there a solution to this?

EDIT: I switched to notepad++ for this particular problem. It works...

Comment: How big are the web pages you are pasting from?

Comment: @troggy: Usually just 1 page or so. I also mainly just want the test, so I select that option, if available. Thanks.

Comment: OF course I meant Text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you give more details? What exactly are you copy/pasting? Maybe only certain elements cause the crash? Or does it crash every single time?

Also, you may want to consider using something lighter to copy/paste web site text, such as Notepad or [Notepad++](http://notepad-plus.sourceforge.net/uk/site.htm).

Comment: Thanks for your response.

I am only trying to copy text.

It doesn't always hang but very often. I've considered that there might be another element rather than text selected, but that does not seem to be the case.

Why do you think that those less capable programs might work instead?

Comment: They are hardly less capable. I'm suggesting using something different because either 1) Your Office 03 may need reinstalled 2) Office 03 may have problems with this functionality (possibly hidden things being copied/pasted)

Comment: Word may attempt to copy pictures and other elements of the web page (pics, formatting, etc). With a simple program like notepad++, it would just copy the text because that is all they can handle.

Comment: Thanks for these suggestions.
FYI, I experienced this same problem with earlier versions of Word.

Answer (score 0):

Pasting text from a text file should be no problem. Pasting text from a Web page can cause problems, depending on the content of the web page.

I would recommend using a paste unformatted if you absolutely must use Word. It sounds like a simple text editor is all you really need though.

We can probably give you a better answer if you offer a link to example Web content that causes this issue.

Comment: Thanks. I have gone to notepad++. I don't understand your confusion?? It is web info in both cases.

Comment: At first it seemed that you used "Word" and "text file" interchangeably, no big deal. I edited my post.